complex eigenvalues of a real symmetric matrix
I am solving a standard eigenvalue problem Ax =lambda x, where A is a real symmetric matrix. A is perfectly symmetric and can be decomposed into LL.T using cholesky decompositon, suggesting A is positive definite as well. I have tried solving it using numpy.linalg.eig which gives complex eigenvalues. Since eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix should not be complex, I tried solving it using numpy.linalg.eigh, but this time some of the eigenvalues are negative, suggesting that the matrix A is not positive definite. From physical context, the matrix A should be real and symmetric, with positive and real eigenvalues. What is it that I am doing wrong, and what should I do?

This is a math question, not an implementation question.  And it's not even a complete math question.  You've basically just asked "I should have a positive definite matrix, but I don't; why?"

How large is your matrix? Can you share it along with your code?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Is this related to the python bug described in Q 78989038, where the result contains an imaginary part when it should not?  Just a hunch.
